# can we set text on RowHeader Column in nebulla Grid in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: grid, eclipse-rcp

I have a Nebula Grid (org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.Grid) control in my view in Eclipse RCP.  I would to make the row header of this grid visible so that, at runtime it displays row numbers like following photo:

[image]

Now, my requirement is that I want to display a text/char on the row header column, like other column headers (e.g. Full Name, Designation, etc). How can I achieve this on the Nebula Grid?  Or, is it not possible by this Nebula Grid control?  What could be my alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally achieved the required functionality in nebulla Grid by implementing the method : 
public void paint(GC paramGC, Object paramObject) {implementaion code } 
inside interface : 
setTopLeftRenderer(new IRenderer() { //interface methods}
as follows :

```
grdTable.setTopLeftRenderer(new IRenderer() {
    @Override
    public void setSize(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(Point paramPoint) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }           
    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean paramBoolean) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void setMouseDown(boolean paramBoolean) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(Point paramPoint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
    }

    @Override
    public void setHover(boolean paramBoolean) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus(boolean paramBoolean) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }

    @Override
    public void setExpanded(boolean paramBoolean) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }

    @Override
    public void setDisplay(Display paramDisplay) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3,
                    int paramInt4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(Rectangle paramRectangle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(GC paramGC, Object paramObject) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //paramGC.setAntialias(1);
    paramGC.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(240, 240, 240));
    Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 2*(grdTable.getGroupHeaderHeight()));
        paramGC.fillRectangle(rect);
        //making foreground color of the Rectangle to be of text in ColumnHeaders   
    paramGC.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(0, 0, 0));
        //drawing appropriate text on the topLeftCorner of Grid
    paramGC.drawText("#",5,10,false);               
    }

    @Override
    public Point computeSize(GC paramGC, int paramInt1, int paramInt2,
                    Object paramObject) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;
    }
});
```

Where, grdTable is the Grid being used in the view.

Answer (score 1):

The more convenient way is to use GridTableViewer:

```
        GridTableViewer grid = new GridTableViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER
            | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    grid.getGrid().setRowHeaderVisible(true);
    grid.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    grid.setRowHeaderLabelProvider(new CellLabelProvider() {

        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
            cell.setText(cell.getElement().toString());
        }
    });
```